# Django celery task execution

Tags: django, celery-task

I have 3 tasks in tasks.py file when demon is working only one task execute . Rest of two display in debug mode but not execute.

```
celery worker --concurrency=1
```

Is there any changes need ?

Edit :

```
@celery.decorators.periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))
def task1():
    try:
        sc = SampleCount.objects.get(pk=1)
    except:
        sc = SampleCount()
    sc.num = sc.num + 1
    sc.save()
    return(sc)
```

same **task2** for add data into `SampleCount2(minute=2)` and **task3** for add data into SampleCount3(minute=3).
Now i run

```
python manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=DEBUG
```

so it will display 3 task. but when I check status its display only 1 **task1** active . No other two in scheduled.if i run

```
python manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=DEBUG
```

command again then **task3** is active and rest of two not working. How to run three task using one worker .

I have wait till 10 minute but only one task working(may be its **task1**, or **task2** or **task3** ).

Comment: 1. `python manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=DEBUG` will not display tasks, it can display just information about workers. 2. What [broker](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/#broker-overview) do you use? 3. How do you check task status? 4. Have you tried to insert `print` statement in you tasks and to watch celeryd console output?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what resources are available on server.

There is not such requirement, that number of tasks must be equal to number of workers. The only thing is needed to understand:

**the more workers are running, the faster all tasks will be processed, but more server resources will be needed**.

This command:

```
celery worker --concurrency=1
```

Will spawn two processes

```
1. Control process, that will manage workers
2. worker process, the one, that will actually do the job
```

And this command:

```
celery worker --concurrency=2
```

Will spawn three processes

```
1. Control process, that will manage workers
2. worker process #1, the one, that will actually do the job
2. worker process #2, the one, that will actually do the job
```

And so on.

One worker can process all of your tasks, but two worker will do it faster.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I have checked using below code. 
from celery.task.control import inspect . i.active()
 above command sent me one task that is active and when i checked i.sheduled() then it sent me empty . In debug mode i have checked and its display 3 task but execute only one . Thanks again for valuable reply.

Comment: @user3752103 1 worker can execute only 1 task at current time, i.e. one worker will process task one by one, not in parallel, if i understand the question correctly.

Comment: I have three task scheduled at a different time. but when i check in debug only one task is in working . Suppose i have task1, task2, task3. When after stop and start again its run only task1 and no other task scheduled . Second time i start after stop it take task3 as active and no other scheduled end so on..  thanks again for reply asap as i am working on production now.

Comment: @user3752103 currently don't understand clearly the question. Show, how do you schedule tasks, and provide simplified code of your tasks.

Comment: i have edited code with simplify. Need your help. Thanks again